# Problemas con index. Insertar registro en DBF con campos fechas

Tags: c#, index, visual-foxpro

Hola a todos tengo este codigo en un proyecto en C#

```
string strCadenaConexion = @"X://Personal//Bases"; // pasar path desde el appsetting para Insertar.
DBHelperVFPDBF db = new DBHelperVFPDBF(strCadenaConexion);

foreach (var item in lista)
{
    string valuesString = $"INSERT INTO relojjcopiaLuis (id, numdoc, fecha, maquina, tipo, veces, sucursal, transf, forma, audito, newfld)" +
        $" VALUES ('{item.id}',{item.numdoc},DATETIME({item.fecha.Year},{item.fecha.Month},{item.fecha.Day},{item.fecha.Hour},{item.fecha.Minute},{item.fecha.Second})," +
        $" '{item.maquina}','{item.tipo}',{item.veces},'{item.sucursal}',DATETIME({item.transf.Year},{item.transf.Month},{item.transf.Day},0,0,0)," +
        $" '{item.forma}','{item.audito}','{item.newfld}');";
                
    if (db.ProbarConexion())
    {               
        try
        {   
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(valuesString))
            {
                db.EjecutarQuery(command);
                Log.Error($"Se pudo guardar la informacion {item.numdoc} {item.id} ");
            }                          
    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error("No se pudo guardar la informacion " + e.Message);

        }          
    }
    //se divide el los milisegundos con la cantidad de registros para ir impactando la 
    BD
    await Task.Delay(delay/lista.Count); 
              
}
Log.Information($"Se insertaron {lista.Count} nuevas fichadas al Fox")
```

Si revisamos en los archivos que maneja VFP tenemos 3 en mi caso hago alusion a mi tabla

1. relojj.dbf
2. relojj.ftp
3. relojj.cdx

Si elimino el archivo relojj.cdx no tengo inconvenientes para insertar. En cambio con el arhivo relojj.cdx, el cual contiene los indices me tira el siguiente error.

```
Error building key for index "x:\personal\bases\relojjcopiaLuis.cdx" tag "Fecha".
```

Y es que el en cdx se almacenan los index de la tabla y en este caso tengo un index llamado Fecha que tiene una expresion que dice asi TTOC(fecha)+STR(numdoc,8,0)
Este index y expresion fueron armadas desde Visual Fox Pro y son necesaria por lo cual no tengo opcion de borrarla y este proyecto de C# hace insert cada 1 hora, por tanto no es opcion insertar en determinado momento habiendo borrado el .cdx y luego crear el index tan cual existe ahora.
Lo otro CURIOSO y como dato importante es que si le borro esta expresion y dejo por ejemplo dejo un simple ASC tampoco hay inconvenientes

En algunos foros lei que era una cuestion de cantidad de caracteres, en otro puede que al reordenar el index este esta funcion no se llega a completar por formatos de fecha, pero en la tabla figura tal cual se ha insertado de forma directa desde Visual Fox Pro. Est ultimo es el que mas sentido tiene ya que si borro la expresion como dije anteriormente no hay inconvenientes
como se ve en el campo es 18/10/2023 20:34:15

ALGUIEN TIENE ALGUNA IDEA DE COMO SE PUEDE CORREGIR ESTO.